# Wildcard subdomain returning ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: dns, subdomain

I am trying to configure a wildcard subdomain that will redirect all the subdomains to my main domain.

subdomain.newbuildhomesaz.com -> newbuildhomesaz.com

I created the wildcard subdomain *.newbuildhomesaz.com in the cPanel. I checked the DNS configuration and the A Record was created and it looks fine.

I then edited the .htaccess file with the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.newbuildhomesaz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://newbuildhomesaz.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

I can access the main domain newbuildhomesaz.com

However when I try to access a random subdomain like abc.newbuildhomesaz.com I get an error message:

```
This site can’t be reached

abc.newbuildhomesaz.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I have been on the phone with Hostgator throughout the day and they don't seem to be able to help me.

I am on a shared hosting plan with them.

Comment: As of 2017.03.15-01:54 UTC `nslookup abc.newbuildhomesaz.com NS8331.HOSTGATOR.COM` still reports `** server can't find abc.newbuildhomesaz.com: NXDOMAIN`. That's on their DNS, not from propagation.

Answer (score 2):

If `newbuildhomesaz.com.` is your domain, the DNS A record for wildcard subdomains, `*.newbuildhomesaz.com.` is not properly configured.  No A record is returned:

```
root@node51 [~]# dig '*.newbuildhomesaz.com'

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> *.newbuildhomesaz.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 57822
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;*.newbuildhomesaz.com.         IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
newbuildhomesaz.com.    1799    IN      SOA     ns8331.hostgator.com. root.gator4166.hostgator.com. 2016020100 86400 7200 3600000 86400

;; Query time: 44 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 14 20:23:45 CDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 118
```

If you are certain that there is an A record for `*.newbuildhomesaz.com.` in cPanel, something has gone wrong on the server that prevented the zone record from being created.

You can verify this by opening a ticket with HostGator, explain the situation, then ask them to run the command `grep '^*' /var/named/newbuildhomesaz.com.db`.  The command should return a line that looks like this:

```
*       14400   IN      A       108.167.133.22
```

If there is no such line, the A record was not created.

If that line exists, the BIND DNS configuration has not loaded the new configuration.  The support administrator should run `named-checkzone 'newbuildhomesaz.com' '/var/named/newbuildhomesaz.com.db'` and check that the last line reads "`OK`".  If there is an error, your domain's zone file is broken.

If there is no error, the BIND DNS server needs to be reloaded with `rndc reload`.  The support administrator can then verify that the wildcard subdomain works with `dig '*.newbuildhomesaz.com' A @gator4166.hostgator.com`.

If the wildcard subdomain still does not show an A record, there is something else wrong with the DNS configuration on the server that will require deeper investigation.

**Note:** Since you are a tenant on shared hosting, you cannot make changes to your zone file `/var/named/newbuildhomesaz.com.db` or to the DNS server yourself.  A support administrator with root access will need to do this; phone and chat support cannot do this.

---

### Additional Resources

- Create a support ticket by going to
  [HostGator.com Support Portal](https://support.hostgator.com/) » Quick Links » Create a Ticket.
- [Wildcard DNS, What is it and How Do I Use it?](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/wildcard-dns-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it) on HostGator

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with my issue. I have just spent 1h30min with hostgator support. In the end they said that the A Record was created correctly, but because it is an A record we should wait between 4 and 8 hours for it to propagate. I am at the 5 hour mark. I told them I would wait for the 8 hours and try again. I didn't know subdomains had to propagate. I thought the DNS servers would know to send all the subdomains to Hostgator.

Comment: `dig '*.newbuildhomesaz.com' A @gator4166.hostgator.com` asks the server itself for the wildcard.  There is no A record returned.  Since the DNS server itself doesn't know about your wildcard domain, this is not a propagation issue.

Comment: thank you. That makes sense. I am opening a chat with Hostgator to see if they can finally resolve my issue. I do see the A Record in cPanel.

Comment: Question - in my cPanel I see the following entry *.newbuildhomesaz.com. 14400 IN A 108.167.140.95. Should it be '*.newbuildhomesaz.com' or just '*'? In your response it shows only the '*'. Thanks.

Comment: @jdias: They are equivalent.  `*` and `*.newbuildhomesaz.com.` mean the same thing for your purposes.